# Replace values from one column to another using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
       subtracted      Subs        hrs  
0      281871.120   450878.77      0.00    
1      221343.432   229535.34      0.00     
2      197454.408    32080.93      0.00    
3      41934.000    -9853.07     32080.93
```

i want to replace positive values (With respect to Subs column) from subtracted column to hrs column.

Expected output:

```
       subtracted      Subs        hrs  
0      281871.120   450878.77      281871.120   
1      221343.432   229535.34      221343.432    
2      197454.408    32080.93      197454.408    
3      41934.000    -9853.07       32080.93
```

Can anybody suggest me the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace by mask created by positive values with `loc`, [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html) or [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
m = df['Subs'] > 0
df.loc[m, 'hrs'] = df['subtracted']
```

---

```
df['hrs'] = df['subtracted'].where(m, df['hrs'])
```

---

```
df['hrs'] = np.where(m, df['subtracted'], df['hrs'])
```

---

```
print (df)
   subtracted       Subs         hrs
0  281871.120  450878.77  281871.120
1  221343.432  229535.34  221343.432
2  197454.408   32080.93  197454.408
3   41934.000   -9853.07   32080.930
```

For mask created by negative values is possible use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
m = df['Subs'] < 0
df['hrs'] = np.where(m, df['hrs'], df['subtracted'])
```

---

```
df['hrs'] = df['subtracted'].mask(m, df['hrs'])
```

Comment: can you please give a look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48124946/replace-nan-values-with-the-unique-date-date-in-numpy-array