# Replace nan values with the unique date (date in numpy array.)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have written a code in a for loop:

```
date = dit[x]["Time"].dt.date.unique()

output:
[datetime.date(2017, 6, 5)]
```

I am getting a numpy array.

I have a dataframe like this:

```
   Position  Values  Date
0       1.0  826.18   NaN
1      22.0  828.11   NaN
2      33.0  826.18   NaN
3      56.0  826.09   NaN
```

I want to replace Nan values with the unique date i am getting from the above code.

My approach:

```
peaks_df["Date"] = peaks_df["Date"].replace(np.nan, str(date))
```

## there is an edit.

```
output:

   Position  Values                          Date
0       1.0  826.18  [datetime.date(2017, 6, 5)]
1      22.0  828.11  [datetime.date(2017, 6, 5)]
2      33.0  826.18  [datetime.date(2017, 6, 5)]
3      56.0  826.09  [datetime.date(2017, 6, 5)]
```

Expected Output:

```
   Position  Values    Date
0       1.0  826.18  6/5/2017
1      22.0  828.11  6/5/2017
2      33.0  826.18  6/5/2017
3      56.0  826.09  6/5/2017
```

Can anybody suggest me the correct way to do it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try `df['Date'] = df['Date'].str[0]` . I think it will get you where you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.unique()` returns a list of all unique elements in the selection (there could be more than one).  If you are sure that there will *only* be one date given your data, just access the first (and only) element of the list.  I used a ternary in case the list is empty, in which case it returns a blank string.

```
.replace(np.nan, str(date[0]) if date else "")
```

You can probably notice the source of your problem via this:

```
>>> str([dt.date.today()])
'[datetime.date(2018, 1, 5)]'
```

Your `date` variable is a list containing a single date.  Converting it to a string results in the output above.

Taking the first element of this list, however, would result in your desired outcome:

```
>>> str([dt.date.today()][0])
'2018-01-05'
```

Comment: I have used a for loop.

Comment: And?  First, your code does not correspond to your data, as there is no `Time` column. Second, you don't show the code with the loop. Third, you reference `x` without indicating what it is (a variable in your loop, presumably, but referencing what exactly?) Fourth, you don't provide the error that you are getting.

Comment: Ya there are a lot of errors. Will try to provide proper information from the next time. Thanks.